# Angular: how to change css using ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to change a css style using ViewChild or Renderer2, but I am unable to. Do you have a code example?

Below is the code that does't work.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

public onClick(){                
      this.renderer.setStyle('main-wrapper', 'color', 'blue');   
     }
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```js
export class BypartSubBarComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('subbar', {static: false}) subbar: MatToolbar;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.subbar._elementRef.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', '#ff0000');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument needs to be the element. For example, if your element has the id of main-wrapper, then you could do:

```
const element = document.getElemenetById('main-wrapper');
this.renderer.setStyle(element, "color", "blue");
```

Though, I'd recommend using ViewChild instead:

```
<div #mainWrapperElement>
     ....
</div>

import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('mainWrapperElement') myElement: HTMLElement;
```

then...

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.myElement, "color", "blue");
```

*On a side note, angular has really cool ways to manipulate styles that I would suggest looking into (ngStyle or style binding).*

Comment: thank you so much , but this line using @ViewChild  fails :this.renderer.setStyle(this.myElement, "color", "blue");

Error: "Cannot set property 'color' of undefined  "

Comment: It could be failing for a few reasons. One common reason is that the element is not currently in the view when you run the method. This can happen if the element has not yet loaded, or if you are hiding it under an *ngIf, for example. Make sure the element is defined console.log(this.myElement). and that the element is actually tagged with #variableName